# Ошибка подключения mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Имею свой сайт на одном бесплатном хостинге, который предоставляет mysql. 
Есть такой код

`$link = mysqli_connect('mysql.****.ru','login','parol','bd');`

Если открыть сайт на хостинге, то не будет никаких ошибок, а если открыть его на локальном сервере, то появляются такие ошибки

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in ... on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in ... on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in ... on line 13

Почему так?
Локальный **PHP 7 x64**, **mySQL 5.7 x64**

На хостинге **PHP 7**, **версия mySQL неизвестна**

Comment: Может имя хоста `mysql.****.ru` объявлено на том хостинге только в hosts файле и не доступно из других мест т.к. отсутствует в DNS

Comment: @Mike То есть такое возможно?

Comment: Я бы сказал это единственное разумное объяснение. попробуйте с той машины где не работает дайте ping на это имя и посмотрите найдет оно хотя бы ip или нет. Можете попробовать вместо имени хоста использовать IP, правда на большинстве хостингов MySQL в принципе доступен только с самого хостинга

Comment: @Mike Ping request could not find host mysql.****.ru. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: @Mike говоря про большинство хостингов, вы имели ввиду бесплатные? Если нет, то как тогда работать с сайтом с локальной машины?

Comment: Вы проверьте сначала, потом уточните у хостера, может имени снаружи нет, а по адресу можно или они по запросу могут разрашить. Если совсем закрыто - то работать только через скрипты находящиеся на самом хостинге

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы к серверу MySQL был возможен доступ из вне, на нем должна быть заведена сетевая учетная запись

```
'login'@'hostname'
```

hostname - имя хоста, с которого идет обращение к MySQL - серверу. Можно открыть доступ с любого хоста, задав в качестве хоста любой хост

```
'login'@'%'
```

Однако, хост-провайдеры так поступают редко, скорее всего там указан домен PHP-сервера

```
'login'@'php.****.ru'
```

или пула php-серверов

```
'login'@'%.****.ru'
```

Вы можете попросить тех.поддержку открыть вам удаленный доступ, но вероятность отказа очень высока.